# Problemas com calendário no Smartphone

Tags: jquery, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

Estou com problemas para visualização do calendário, quando estou executando meu aplicativo pelo `IntelXDK` a visualização do calendário é feita desta maneira.

[image: Modelo de exibição quando estou no IntelXDK]

Já quando instalei o aplicativo no célular, teve a seguinte exibição.

[image: Modelo de exibição quando estou no mobile]

Tentei de tudo porém ainda não sei como fazer, Tentei utilizar uma biblioteca `CalendarJS` porém ela nem mesmo abriu no mobile.

Os meus arquivos de imports são

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/geral.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
    <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>
    <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/indexeddbshim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="marginal/marginal-position.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_init_services.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="xdk/ad/ionic_subpage.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/functionAngular.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/swipe-hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="sidebar/js/sidebar.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/mapa.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Como devo proceder, caso a resposta esteja um pouco incompleta me peça que atualizarei.

Comment: Esse é o calendário padrão do android, se abrir o mesmo app no iphone vai vir o calendário padrão dele, aconteceu a mesma coisa comigo, mas não achei ruim não, o usuário ainda consegue escolher a data da mesma forma.

Comment: @AndréVicente O meu problema que preciso que o Usuário saiba o dia da semana, seg, terc, qua, qui ... Sabe como bloquear isto ?